# Egyptian fraction series for $\frac{99}{70}-\sqrt{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, approximation, diophantine-approximation, constants

This question is motivated by series found while answering  [How is the sequence 1, 1.4, 1.41, 1.414 generated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301455/how-is-the-sequence-1-1-4-1-41-1-414-generated)

A fast series for $\sqrt{2}$ is given by the [Egyptian fraction mentioned in the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Square_root_of_2)

$$\sqrt{2}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{a(2^n)}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{204}+\frac{1}{235416}+\dots \right)$$

with denominators defined by $2^n$th terms of a second order recurrence relation $$a(n)=34a(n-1)-a(n-2)$$ with $a(0)=0, a(1)=6$ ([OEIS sequence A082405](https://oeis.org/A082405)).

The corresponding closed form is 
$$\sqrt{2}=\frac{3}{2}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{(17+12\sqrt{2})^{2^k}-(17-12\sqrt{2})^{2^k}}$$

as obtained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2301482/134791).

A similar series seems to exist starting from the closer convergent $\dfrac{99}{70}$, because when applying the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) starting from $\dfrac{7}{5}$ the following sequence is obtained:
$$\frac{7}{5}, \frac{99}{70}, \frac{19601}{13860}, \frac{768398401}{543339720}, \frac{1180872205318713601}{835002744095575440},...$$

and the difference between consecutive approximations has unit numerator, although the fractions are not consecutive convergents, so similarly we have

$$\sqrt{2}=\frac{99}{70}-\frac{1}{13860}-\frac{1}{543339720}-\frac{1}{835002744095575440}-...$$

> Is there an underlying recurrence that can be sampled to obtain the denominators of these negative fractions?

**After the answer**

Formulas for $\dfrac{3}{2}-\sqrt{2}$ (question) and $\dfrac{10}{7}-\sqrt{2}$ (from the answer) can be written in terms of the silver ratio and the index starting from $0$.

$$\sqrt{2} = \frac{3}{2} - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{(1+\sqrt{2})^{2^{k+2}}-(1-\sqrt{2})^{2^{k+2}}}$$

$$\sqrt{2} = \frac{10}{7} - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{(1+\sqrt{2})^{3·2^{k+1}}-(1-\sqrt{2})^{3·2^{k+1}}}$$

**Related questions**

[Numbers $p-\sqrt{q}$ having regular egyptian fraction expansions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910226/numbers-p-sqrtq-having-regular-egyptian-fraction-expansions)

[Newton's method for square roots 'jumps' through the continued fraction convergents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733530/newtons-method-for-square-roots-jumps-through-the-continued-fraction-converge).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We repeatedly apply the mapping $\frac{a}{b} \to \frac{1}{2}(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{2b}{a}) = \frac{a^2 + 2b^2}{2ba}$.

So $a(n+1) = a(n)^2 + 2b(n)^2$ and $b(n+1) = 2a(n)b(n)$.

There's a pattern in $b(n)$. Continuing the pattern: $b(n+2) = 2a(n+1)2a(n)b(n)$.

Generally, $\displaystyle b(n) = 5\cdot2^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a(k)$.

As you've noticed, in $\frac{a^2 + 2b^2}{2ba} - \frac{a}{b} = \frac{2b^2 - a^2}{2ba}$ we have $2b^2 - a^2 = -1$.

$a(n+1) = a(n)^2 + 2b(n)^2 =  a(n)^2 + a(n)^2 - 1 = 2a(n)^2 - 1$.

We  have $a(n) = \cos(2^{n-2} \cos^{-1}(99))$ for $n > 1$.

However, I notice that all $b$ are [Pell numbers](http://oeis.org/A000129), in fact $P(6), P(12), P(24), \dots P(6\cdot 2^n)$.

This gives us a formula for $b$:

$$b(n) = \frac{\sqrt2}{4}\left((7+5\sqrt 2)^{2^{n-1}} - (7-5\sqrt 2)^{2^{n-1}} \right)$$

I don't believe that the $7$ and $5$ constants in the formula are a coincidence.